# How to updates nested object using mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

i'm new to mongoose, I want to update my city_name, my schema structure looks like

```
   const addressSchema = new mongoose.schema({
     address:{
       door_no:{type:number},
       other_details:{
         street_name:{ type: string},
         city:{
           city_name:{type:string},
           pincode:{type:string},
          }
       }
     }
    })
```

sample db data :

```
{
  "_id": "63dw8sdhs8ad0s",
  "address": {
    "door_no": 43,
    "other_details": {
      "street": "sdsadada",
      "city": {
        "city_name": "dfaef"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

now i want to update the city_name i tried this query

`addressModel.findByIdAndUpdate({_id:id},{$set:{'address.other_details.city.city_name':'44xd3xc'}})`

but it doesn't update for me.

Comment: You query is good. Try to `console.log(id)` to see if you are passing correct value for the `id`. Maybe it's undefined.

Comment: It's a findById query so you don't need to write {_id: id}. The parameter will be checked on _id value already. So try it as ;  
  addressModel.findByIdAndUpdate(mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id),{$set:{'address.other_details.city.city_name':'44xd3xc'}})

Comment: thanks NeNaD and Onur Dogan, i resolved issue by defining _id:string in schema, i missed it, because i'm using string id not ObjectID. thanks

Answer (score 1):

*check that you passing id crctly or not*

> https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZDPiTrMUHha

Comment: id is correct, i used findByIdAndUpdate

Comment: thanks nodejs developer, i resolved issue by defining _id:string in schema, i missed it, because i'm using string id not ObjectID. thanks